# How to store array values from $_post to db

Tags: php

i have add an tabular column which adds dynamic rows so when on submit is click the values should be stored in db ,
with php code

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
foreach($_POST AS $key=>$value)
{
$sql = "INSERT INTO `shows` ( `from` ,  `to` ,  `seats` ,  `cost` ,  `screen`  ) VALUES(  '{$_POST['first_name']}' ,  '{$_POST['last_name']}' ,  '{$_POST['tamil']}' ,  '{$_POST['english']}' ,  '{$_POST['computer']}' ) ";
```

i am getting o/p like

```
INSERT INTO `shows` ( `from` , `to` , `seats` , `cost` , `screen` ) VALUES( 'Array' , 'Array' , 'Array' , 'Array' , 'Array' )
```

so only array variables are storing in my db how to store values in my db

Thanks in advance

Ameeth

Comment: Here comes [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Did you try echo or print_r($key), $value and so on?

Comment: first_nameArray ( [0] => 10:00 AM ) last_nameArray ( [0] => 10:00AM ) tamilArray ( [0] => ) englishArray ( [0] => ) computerArray ( [0] => )  this is o/p i got

Comment: how to add actual values to the db without array

Comment: Did you really name you son Array ( [0] => 10:00 AM ) ?

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: yes when print_r($post) o/p is Array ( [first_name] => Array ( [0] => 10:00 AM ) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => 10:00AM ) [tamil] => Array ( [0] => ) [english] => Array ( [0] => ) [computer] => Array ( [0] => ) [submit] => submit )

Comment: You are sending multiple values with the same name. Please, include the code of your HTML form, or we cannot help you.

In the meanwhile, try to google "SQL injection". It might be handy...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach($_POST as $varname => $value) {
        $clean = trim($value);
        $clean = striptags($clean);
        $clean = mysql_real_escape_string($clean); // use inplace of addslashes
        //create sanitized array
        $cleanVars[$varname] = $clean;
    } 

}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `shows` ( from ,  to,  seats ,  cost ,  screen  ) VALUES('. $cleanVars["first_name"].','. $cleanVars["last_name"].','. $cleanVars["english"].','. $cleanVars["tamil"].','. $cleanVars["computer"].' ) ';
?>
```

Comment: for the above code in db array text is stored not the posted values

Comment: post your html form code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QbPQacGF  here is the code

Comment: remove [] from all names and then try this code :P , [] is converting your names to array which you don't require in this case..

Comment: example `name='tamil[]'` should be `name='tamil'`

Comment: I HAVE a different case if provide ur mail id i'll send my files that u'll understand what i'm trying to do

Comment: i inserted code above mentioned its working but only for single values if we pass array of values from $_post textfiled its errors out like Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\css12\manage_shows.php on line 312

Comment: yes that is obvious learn from code i dint bake a cake for you to eat

Comment: i would advice you to learn basics of arrays and foreach before jumping in to code

Comment: ok if possible give me ur mail id i'll send my code so tht i may resolve my prob